# the folder is restricted from being deleted

Tags: 2010, document-library, sharepoint-server, delete

i need help for delete some empty folder

i've a document library and having some empty folder inside.
If i go to managed permission on the folder i can't delete it, i see the group with full control and inside this group i've my user.

I try everything to delete this but nothing works

Do you have a solution for having permission to delete folders?

Thanks

Comment: try open IE as admin, then delete.

Answer (score 1):

what error you are getting?

Couple of things, i would do to fix this.

1. I will check recycle bin(both level) and make sure no refrecne to library exist here
2. [i would also try to take the ownership of the all checked out documents in that library] or [this](http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/articles/pages/manage-checked-out-files.aspx)[1](http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/articles/pages/manage-checked-out-files.aspx).
3. also make sure content approval is turned off
4. you have full control on Library or folders?

Comment: i have full control on both library and folders. th eerror receive is in title: the folder is restricted from being deleted

Comment: i've checked and content approval is turned off. How can i check the first and second point?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue, there were an event itemdeleting with a redirect